# Saving a file in a directory but also being able to print it whenever i needto

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, save

I am running Python 3.x. So i have been working on some code for fetching data on currencies names around the world from a currency website to get information which the code is as follows

```
def _fetch_currencies():
    import urllib.request
    import json
    f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json')
    charset = f.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
    data = f.read()
    decoded = json.loads(data.decode(charset))
    dumps = json.dumps(decoded, indent=4)
    return dumps
```

I then need to save it as a file locally but having some issue and cant see where.

Here is the code for saving the currencies:

```
def save_currencies(_fetch_currencies, filename):   
    sorted_currencies = sorted(decoded.items())
    with open(filename, 'w') as my_csv:
       csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
       csv_writer.writerows(sorted_currencies)
```

They just don't seem to work together apart from when i remove the line ' dumps = json.dumps(decoded, indent=4) ' but i need that line to be able to print the file in text, how do i get around deleting this line and still be able to save and print? How do i also pick where it saves?

Any Help will be great, thank you very much anyone and everyone who answers/reads this.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but your "decoded" variable should be declared as global in *both* functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually have _fetch_currencies() return a dictionary, and then I would pass that dictionary on to saved_currencies(currencies_decoded, filename). For example:

```
def _fetch_currencies():
    import urllib.request
    import json
    f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json')
    charset = f.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
    data = f.read()
    decoded = json.loads(data.decode(charset))
    return decoded

def save_currencies(currencies_decoded, filename):   
    sorted_currencies = sorted(currencies_decoded.items())
    with open(filename, 'w') as my_csv:
       csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
       csv_writer.writerows(sorted_currencies)

my_currencies_decoded = _fetch_currencies()
save_currencies(my_currencies_decoded, "filename.csv")
```

Furthermore, if you would like to save your csv file to a certain location in your filesystem, you can import os and use the os.path.join() function and provide it the FULL path. For example, to save your .csv file to a location called "/Documents/Location/Here", you can do:

```
import os

def save_currencies(currencies_decoded, filename):   
    sorted_currencies = sorted(currencies_decoded.items())
    with open(os.path.join("Documents","Location","Here"), 'w') as my_csv:
       csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
       csv_writer.writerows(sorted_currencies)
```

You can also use a relative path, so that if you're already in directory "Documents", and you'd like to save a file in "/Documents/Location/Here", you can instead just say:

```
with open(os.path.join("Location", "Here"), 'w') as my_csv:
```